# how to use php thumb in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, phpthumb

I am using webino/WebinoImageThumb module to generate thumbnail in my zend 2 application but it shows an error
"Fatal error: Class 'GD' not found ..."
Is there is any other module or library available to do this like php thumb etc.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message obviously says the problem. You need the [GD extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) enabled on your system to use image processing capabilities of **WebionoImageThumb** module.

You should read [installation documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php) and follow the steps described there.